# Azure point in time restore - Query for checking progress

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Is there a way to check the progress percent of azure point in time restored databases?
I started a restore of a 750 Gb database, and i do not know whether it has started the restore and the progress percent.

I checked in almost all the system views, but cant find any view that would help me.

Attaching screen shot of how i started the SQL Restore.

[image]

Comment: how did you start the restore, are you talking about the Azure SQL database?

Comment: Yeah. thats right. Started using Restore option in the Azure portal and selected a time to restore to.

Comment: You could try the following [Get-AzureSqlDatabaseOperation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicemanagement/azure/get-azuresqldatabaseoperation?view=azuresmps-4.0.0) in Azure's Cloud Shell.  To the right of Search at top of Azure Portal.  Would take some googling to figure out how to the command so not sure this is helpful.  This might be helpful as well [sys.dm_operation_status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-operation-status-azure-sql-database?view=azuresqldb-current)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At this time, a detailed restore progress is not available on the portal. You can vote for this feature [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/17235935-track-sql-db-restore-progress) and it may be considered for future implementation by Azure SQL Database team.

However you can run the following query on the Master database of the Azure SQL Database server to track the progress of a restore.

```
SELECT major_resource_id, percent_complete
FROM sys.dm_operation_status 
WHERE operation LIKE '%DATABASE RESTORE%'
```

Comment: How is the percentage figure determined? Is it reliable and meaningful (e.g. when it says "50%" that means it's restored 50% of all bytes, or all rows - or 50% of all tables?)

Comment: Update: I had to babysit an Azure SQL point-in-time restore last night that took 40 minutes to restore a 200GB database. After 20 minutes in I polled the `dm_operation_status` table every minute and it **always** reported “50%” in `percent_complete` - right until the last minute before it jumped to 100%. Let me tell you it was a very frustrating and stressful 40 minutes of not knowing what was going on as business-critical data was being recovered. Not being able to give any kind of ETA to my boss sucks :/

Comment: You will see reported 0%, 50% or 100% only.

Answer (score 2):

As of March 30th 2022 the column `percent_column` in sys.dm_operation_status DMV has been enhanced to display the progress of Database Restore operation at a more granular level. percent_complete column in sys.dm_operation_status DMV will now show percent progress as a continuous value from 0 to 99 instead of 50 earlier.

**Source:**
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/monitor-database-restore-progress-at-more-granular-level/ba-p/3268577

Run the query below against the `master` Azure database. Run `SELECT * FROM sys.time_zone_info;` to find your timezone name and use it in the second `AT TIME ZONE` if you care about seeing date and times in your local timezone.

```sql
SELECT
    DatabaseName     = major_resource_id
   ,RestoreState     = state_desc
   ,PercentComplete  = percent_complete
   ,StartTime        = start_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time'
   ,LastModifyTime   = last_modify_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time'
   ,ErrorCode        = error_code
   ,ErrorDescription = error_desc
   ,ErrorSeverity    = error_severity
   ,ErrorState       = error_state
FROM
    sys.dm_operation_status
WHERE
    operation = N'DATABASE RESTORE'
ORDER BY
    start_time DESC;
```